# cargo shuttle run fails due to resolver defaults

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, shuttle

When running `cargo shuttle run` in my project's directory,
I got the following error message

```
warning: some crates are on edition 2021 which defaults to `resolver = "2"`, but virtual workspaces default to `resolver = "1"`
note: to keep the current resolver, specify `workspace.resolver = "1"` in the workspace root's manifest
note: to use the edition 2021 resolver, specify `workspace.resolver = "2"` in the workspace root's manifest
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a project that uses the the [cargo workspaces](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html) feature. The solution was to define the resolver in the root directory's **Cargo.toml**.

```
[workspaces]
resolver = "2"
```

For [Rust edition 2021](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2021/default-cargo-resolver.html) the preferred way is to declare the edition in the **Cargo.toml**. The resolver then defaults to 2 for Rust 2021.

```
edition = "2021"
```